# Planning Unit Tests for Layers

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have three layers: Service, Domain Model and Mapper.  Should I write separate unit tests for each layer?  Or should I write a set for Services that give me 100% code coverage over the lower layers?

If the answer is that I should write three separate sets of tests, is it important to isolate these tests so that they can run independently of the other layers?  And what order should I write them in?  Domain, then mapper, then services?

I'm using PHP and PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I write separate unit tests for each layer?

Yes you should, as this ensures each layer works on its own what is a basic concept of *unit* testing

> is it important to isolate these tests so that they can run independently of the other layers?

Yes they should be independent

> And what order should I write them in?

The order doesn't matter, as they are independent

Comment: Hi hek2mgl.  Since my mappers are highly dependent on my domain, is there any point in being able to test these independently of the domain layer?  I could mock the domain, but there seems little point.  Similarly, my services are highly dependent on my mapper and domain, so is it really worthwhile mocking out the two lower layers?

Comment: I did not checked your comment that day I gave the answer. Are your questions resolved?